# Retrieve Keycloak attributes in access_token

Tags: spring-boot, permissions, jwt, keycloak, access-token

I can't get `permissions` that a `role` has defined in my `access_token`.
I defined 3 roles (with `Keycloak`): `ADMIN`, `GUEST` and `SUPERADMIN`.

`SUPERADMIN` has `read`, `write` and `gestion` permissions (p_Read, p_Write and p_gestion).

[image: Keycloak permissions configured for SUPERADMIN]

With `postman`, `SUPERADMIN` do login, and gets the obfuscated `access_token`.
When I deobfuscate it, I get the following information (which is correct)

```
"iat": 1654784756,
  "jti": "6bc716df-66fc-47ad-9eaf-8ef252969c61",
  "iss": "https://dev.mydomain.com/auth/realms/Licenses",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "55552ce7-3f92-49a7-835f-7cd356a34d7e",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "Licenses",
  "session_state": "1cb9ac94-0d53-423c-9cd6-66472c8ce02b",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "SUPERADMIN",
      "offline_access",
      "default-roles-licenses",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "Licenses": {
      "roles": [
        "SUPERADMIN"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "Pepe",
  "preferred_username": "pepe@user.com",
  "given_name": "Pepe",
  "family_name": "Pepe",
  "email": "pepe@user.com"
```

but, I don't receive the permissions configured for `SUPERADMIN`. I need to receive the "p_Read","p_Write" and "p_Gestion" permissions in my `access_token`.

Am I missing some setting or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how did you define those "permissions" ? it seems there are attributes but not permission.

Comment: You need to define the values as permissions instead of attributes OR define a mapper for the specific client is which maps the attributes into the JWT Token. For the permission you could define a composite permission called superadmin which contains all three permissions and assign this composite role / permission to the specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get attributes by Get role API.
Also user needs the "manage-realm" role when you get the token.

Steps

1. Assign "manage-realm" to user
   [image]
2. Get Token
   [image]
   [image]
3. Get Role
   [image]