# Keycloak public key is not base64url encoded

Tags: jwt, keycloak, signed

I copied public key from my realm settings and tried to validate in https://jwt.io. It says "Error: Looks like your JWT header is not encoded correctly using base64url". I am using the key to authenticate by sending it has client_assertion. Any help on how to get or generate correct JWT in Keycloak is so much appreciated

Header and Payload section is blank in jwt.io

Comment: After get the access_token from Keycloak, if copy it into jwt.io, jwt.io shows automatically  in VERIFY SIGNATURE section. It create by jwt.io website with access_token's  header and payload value. It should be match, return value of {keyclaok url}/auth/realms/[realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs 's "n" value.

Comment: @BenchVue It gives blank in the header and payload sections. That is the problem

Comment: In the jwt.io, first step is paste the access token in to the Encoded section, then header and payload section will be there. It should not be blank.
You can see how to get the access token in here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564752/retrieve-keycloak-attributes-in-access-token/72573642#72573642

Comment: @BenchVue I think the confusion is between the access token and public key. I need a public key to get the access token.

Comment: Just want to get the public key, two steps #1 get n from "{keyclaok url}/auth/realms/[realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
#2 convert from n to public key. Using node or python code.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsa-pem-from-mod-exp
** again the public key, auto calculate by jwt.io with access token.

Comment: I added answer, you want to public key and get the JWT with your own header and payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a Java program using JJWT library to generate JWT from the JKS file that is generated from Client-Keys-Generate new keys and certificate section and was able to validate JWT and signature in jwt.io

Answer (score 0):

This is steps to create Public Key and create a JWT

1. Switching Algorithm is "RS256" in JWT.io
   the public key and private key will generate by JWO.io
2. Update header and payload section
   the token will be generate in Encoded section
   [image]

if you want to generate public key from Keycloak.

1. call cert API and copy n value
   [image]
2. paste this node java-script and run it by "node get-publick-key.js"

```
//getPem = function(modulus_base);
var getPem = require('rsa-pem-from-mod-exp');

//modulus should be a base64/base64Url string
var modulus =  "388m-vc59JVeHP6kbHRtykkky41sby3gldYs8JY3I6xrI_cUs7dbCLDeVtPq78359sGujTtVrT6-P_VOPQqwJEWQQJ3Yvw5zpX510o5UBHob-qmbTopvB0tiJPBi-GXU_Vwx84unR6udVaXXg_FODxqP-vQS7wPwt_omdPW8a5gp8H3uhqEckNxGd2Cp7mFwC2rcwEjBpZBFGoQo8lvGpYBCzzPfSEkET-CvAnrMM8AhqtC0qRhBBfOdzYDclxJYmXb2wz8OhIflgySOMrhdG-oqugp4wxLk2fE528Sz6tdhFwRgWwcOKFxvPNW6-0puRCbW3vKV89jhXMuwtE6aXQ";

//exponent should be base64/base64url
var exponent = "AQAB";

var pem = getPem(modulus, exponent);
console.log(pem);
```

it will be print public key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA388m+vc59JVeHP6kbHRtykkky41sby3gldYs8JY3I6xrI/cUs7db
CLDeVtPq78359sGujTtVrT6+P/VOPQqwJEWQQJ3Yvw5zpX510o5UBHob+qmbTopv
B0tiJPBi+GXU/Vwx84unR6udVaXXg/FODxqP+vQS7wPwt/omdPW8a5gp8H3uhqEc
kNxGd2Cp7mFwC2rcwEjBpZBFGoQo8lvGpYBCzzPfSEkET+CvAnrMM8AhqtC0qRhB
BfOdzYDclxJYmXb2wz8OhIflgySOMrhdG+oqugp4wxLk2fE528Sz6tdhFwRgWwcO
KFxvPNW6+0puRCbW3vKV89jhXMuwtE6aXQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: I have written Java program for this and was able to verify the signature in jtw.io.