# Keycloak - user attributes that are specific to groups

Tags: keycloak, identity-management

I'm using Keycloak as an identity provider in my app. However, I could not find anywhere how to give a user an attribute whose value would be specific to a group. For example : a role within the group ("user", "admin"...), a “pending invitation” status, etc.

Is this even possible, or should I make an external table in my database, mapping user ids with group ids and adding the other attributes ? This additionnal table would be bothersome in terms of architecture.

Have a great day !

Antoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak doesn't support assigning attributes/roles with the group scope. It only supports having roles that are "client" specific. As you mentioned yourself, you have to implement a custom provider and persist them in your own storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can set user's attribute with role name/id and status.

This API call can do

**PUT {Keycloak URL}/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}** OR

**PUT {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}**

it depends on you Keycloak verion.

And Get user's value by this API

**GET {Keycloak URL}/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/?username={user-name}** OR

**GET {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/?username={user-name}**

This demo by Postman.
Set user's attributes
[image]

Get user's attributes
[image]

Get token and set token reference this answer part.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564752/retrieve-keycloak-attributes-in-access-token/72573642#72573642)

Comment: How the "Pending invitation" attribute that you mentioned is scoped to a specific group?

Comment: No it is not linked with role at all. It is hard-cord  part as same as he mentioned example.  I agree as you mentioned role and user attribute coupled is not good idea by own custom logic.

Comment: The reason I asked was that the original question is about how to have an attribute that is bound to a specific group, not how to generally add an attribute to a user

Comment: It's still kind of a good workaround, since the key of the attribute can be the id of the group.

Comment: Yes, you can put any key and values in user's attribute. It needs to extras custom logic and code.