# Keycloak - PATCH user attributes through REST API

Tags: attributes, keycloak, patch

I am using Keycloak docker image 21.0.2 (the latest one).

I make a PUT request to this URL:
 `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/custom-realm/users/14905db1-5229-4110-bfbb-df13845a4f52`
and with this JSON body to edit a user's attributes:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "organization_id": "1"
    }
}
```

The problem is that this wipes out all user attributes and I want it to keep the old ones as they are used for other functionalities and cannot be wiped out.

I just want to append or replace 'organization_id' value in the list of user attributes.

I think it should be a PATCH request but Keycloak doesn't have one for users. Is there any way to make this work?

I tried to update user attributes through the ADMIN REST API but I think a PATCH method is missing...

Comment: You can do it by "PUT {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}" in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105467/keycloak-user-attributes-that-are-specific-to-groups/73106895#73106895)

Comment: Hi there, This does not work, as explained in my comment it will override ALL attributes of the specific user and what I want is override 1 attribute in the list, not all of them...

Comment: There is no PATCH command, you need to get attributes first and then to update the organization_id with other attributes to keep by PUT command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I was thinking the same and wondering if there was any other way to do that but it looks like a PATCH command is missing in the API...

Comment: @NTeix with 23.0.6 - when using the **Java** Rest client at least - PUT seems to behave like a patch would. Maybe this helps

Comment: Did you try replacing a specific attribute ? not the entire list ?

Comment: @NTeix I updated the `enabled` flag and the role, using the `UserResource.update()` method and all other attributes (firstname, email, other attributes) stayed the same.

Comment: Is there any way to know the exact http request sent by your Java rest client ? (body, method, headers, endpoint?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and i finally resolve it by fetching first the information of the user and made a custom merge when updating the user with the keycloak admin client.
It's not a fancy solution, but Keycloak at this date does not provide a way to partially update the user.

Comment: I opened an open issue on their github for this, but it is not prioritary... https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/19691